# include group by in c# linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have this linq query which I want to include group by some specific fields:

```
 from x in db.Schedule
 join y in db.Schedule on x.ID equals y.ID - 1
 join z in db.Locations on x.Line.ToString() + '-' + x.Expedition equals z.LocationCode
 where Convert.ToInt32(y.StopOrder) >= Convert.ToInt32(x.StopOrder) && x.NameOfTown == departingBusStation && dest.Contains(x.Line)
 where x.NameOfTown == departingBusStation
 select new { x.NameOfLine, x.DepartureTime, x.DestBusStationCode, x.StopOrder, z.LocationID }
```

In that linq query I want to add a group by `x.DestBusStationCode` and `x.DepartureTime` but modifying the query to something like this:

```
 from x in db.Schedule
 join y in db.Schedule on x.ID equals y.ID - 1
 join z in db.Locations on x.Line.ToString() + '-' + x.Expedition equals z.LocationCode
 where Convert.ToInt32(y.StopOrder) >= Convert.ToInt32(x.StopOrder) && x.NameOfTown == departingBusStation && dest.Contains(x.Line)
 where x.NameOfTown == departingBusStation
 orderby x.DepartureTime ascending
 group x by new {x.DepartureTime, x.DestBusStationCode}
 select new { x.NameOfLine, x.DepartureTime, x.DestBusStationCode, x.StopOrder, z.LocationID }
```

But I'm getting multiple errors with that approach.

Comment: Instead of just downvoting, at least tell the threadstarter WHY it was downvoted?

Comment: @Recipe Users are not required to comment when downvoting, but not even including the error message that the code generates sounds like a good place to start for me.  Combine that with a lack of explanation of what the code should do and the question is very much unanswerable.

Comment: screenshot with errors I'm getting: http://i.gyazo.com/67b2da21e7b42589b7035940959f637c.png

Comment: @Laziale Include the errors you have, as text, in your question, not as a link to an image in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you group by something you can only have those properties in your select plus any aggregate value such as `Count` and `Sum`. This is because you are saying give me a single row where the grouped by properties are the same, so other properties may have multiple values for the group. The following would group by `DepartureTime` and `DestBusStationCode`

```
from x in db.Schedule
                 join y in db.Schedule on x.ID equals y.ID - 1
                 join z in db.Locations on x.Line.ToString() + '-' + x.Expedition equals z.LocationCode
                 where Convert.ToInt32(y.StopOrder) >= Convert.ToInt32(x.StopOrder) && x.NameOfTown == departingBusStation && dest.Contains(x.Line)
                 where x.NameOfTown == departingBusStation
                 orderby x.DepartureTime ascending
                 group x by new {x.DepartureTime, x.DestBusStationCode} grp
                 select new { grp.Key.DepartureTime, grp.Key.DestBusStationCode }
```

You can no longer include `NameOfLine`, `StopOrder` and `LocationId` in your results because these properties may differ among any given group with the same `DepartueTime and`DestBusStationCode`.

Comment: Thanks @ben-robinson, so what are my options to select the fields I have but not have duplicate rows based on DepartureTime and DestBusStationCode?

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you can't. If you have for example 2 records with the same DepartureTime and DestBusStationCode each record may have different NameOfLine, StopOrder and LocationId.